# ServiceStack.ServiceInterface dll is missing

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-auth

I am trying to use [Authentication Plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) of ServiceStack. I added NuGet packages for ServiceStack 4.0.11 but I am unable to find DLL ServiceStack.ServiceInterface which contains the AuthService and Auth classes. I think [Authentication Plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) is dependent on this DLL. How can i add ServiceStack.ServiceInterface to my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you might have a version mismatch. That dll has been merged to the main one. Per [ServiceStack v4 release notes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes):

> ServiceStack.Interfaces NuGet project created and ServiceInterface has
>   been merged into ServiceStack

Comment: You are right. They have renamed the classes as well from AuthService to AuthenticateService and Auth to Authenticate. But they are still mentioning old class names in online documentation.